# Turtlebot - get distance from laser to wall

Tags: ros, kinect, laser, turtlebot, range

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get the distance between the turtlebot kinect laser to  a wall - could someone point me in the right direction - i've just started using the turtlebot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31299/turtlebot---get-distance-from-laser-to-wall./) by [AmaneSuzuha](https://answers.ros.org/users/1879/amanesuzuha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the `LaserScan` message that the turtlebot publishes; this is a horizontal slice through the point cloud generated by the Kinect. The turtlebot uses this message as input to various techniques (like gmapping) that expect a two-dimensional laser scan as input.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1